# Using socket.io-client in a server component

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, socket.io

I've managed to get [socket.io](https://socket.io) working between my Next.js server component (using `socket.io`) and a browser client side component (using `socket.io-client`). Now I'd like to be able to have another server component join and send/receive messages just like the client component. However, when I attempt to use `socket.io-client` on the server side nothing seems to happen (it never connects and there's no error message). Is this even possible or is there another way? Sample code below (and looks nearly the same in my client component where it's working):

```
"use server"
import { Socket, io } from "socket.io-client";

let socket: Socket;
await socketInitializer();

//TODO: This is not working--never connects (but does in client component).
async function socketInitializer() {
  const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/io";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(`${response.statusText} (layout.tsx)`); // Returns OK
  socket = io(url);

  // This never fires, nor do any other events below
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("layout.tsx component is connected to socket.io endpoint");
  });

  socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(`Message received by component: ${msg}`);
  });

  socket.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(`Error connecting: ${error.message}`);
  });
}
```